# Negative elevation results from USGS 1 meter DEM

Tags: dem, elevation, usgs

The USGS 1 meter Digital Elevation Model will return negative elevations. The elevations are based off NAVD88. The negative elevations appear to be near/over water along coastal areas. This DEM is created from [lidar data](https://www.usgs.gov/faqs/what-lidar-data-and-where-can-i-download-it).

Edited question: Are lidar points over water accurate representations of the water's surface?

Original question: Are negative elevations derived from points on waterbodies accurate measures of the water's elevation?

Here is an example negative elevation result using their API for coordinate 26.68215007412314, -81.81595196876486, shoreline of Caloosahatchee River in Florida:

https://epqs.nationalmap.gov/v1/json?x=-81.81595196876486&y=26.682150074123143&units=Feet&wkid=4326&includeDate=False

The use case here is to determine the height of a land point above a source of water.

Comment: Please [Edit] the Question to describe what you mean by "handled". There are a number of places below sea level in the US. Some are man-made, like parts of New Orleans, others are as natural as Death Valley.

Answer (score 1):

"Are negative elevations derived from points on waterbodies accurate measures of the water's elevation?" **No**.  A quick check from the National Map in the area of the Caloosatchee River returned some important information relevant to your question.  See the image below.

[See this link](https://www.usgs.gov/ngp-standards-and-specifications/3d-elevation-program-standards-and-specifications) if you would like to further investigate the quality of the source data for the 3DEP program.

[image]

Comment: It's most likely elevation at low tide

Comment: Yes, all points queried are technically an estimate as they are derived from a digital elevation model, which is modeling elevations through interpolation of lidar data. I should further clarify my question to indicate if a negative elevation estimate of the waterbody is a usable estimate. I guess what I'm really wondering is related to the lidar data. Are lidar points over water accurate representations of the water surface?

Comment: Water surfaces change over time.  You would have to look at the actual point cloud data to determine the time of data capture and then determine the tide level at that time to answer that.  As FelixIP states, the data maybe was captured at a lower tide level but this is not a guarantee.  Also, the data may have been collected with topo-bathymetric LiDAR.   0 NAVD88 - the vertical datum of the 3DEP - may not be the same as a 0 tide level.  A vertical datum conversion would be in order to sort all that out.  Find the LiDAR report and find the expected accuracy - which will within a few cm.

Comment: Thank you, @GBG. This helps my understanding greatly.